# Post/Comment to a private facebook group

Tags: facebook

I want to programmatically comment to a specific post of mine in a private facebook group. Seem like I can't no longer do that in the version after 2.3 (sadly the 2.3 is going to be removed soon). Am I correct? Can I implement this function with the latest API? If not, should I try to implement it without the Graph API 9 (try to decipher the Post request, which doesn't seem like an easy task).

Comment: if you are not admin of the group, there is no way. and no, you should not try to implement anything without the graph api, because that would not be allowed.

Comment: Thanks. What's about Imacro?  I'm not going to spam. Just auto-comment 10 times a day so that my sale post can get noticed. I do it by hand everyday anyways.

Comment: That is the very definition of spam.

Comment: rule of thumb: if it is not possible with the api, it is most likely not allowed. and yes, that would definitely be spam.

Comment: @luschn, how about I am the admin of the group, how to programmatically make comments in private group?

Comment: check out the api reference for that. this is way too broad for stackoverflow right now, show us what you have tried so far. "can i do xy?" is off topic, just try ;)